# Port 4466 already in use error after migrating from GraphQL Yoga to Apollo Server 2

Tags: docker, port, apollo-server, prisma

I have a local app that had a backend of Prisma and GraphQL Yoga. I migrated from Yoga to Apollo Server 2 and believe I have the configuration set up correctly. However, when I go to 'run dev' I am getting an error that port 4466 is already in use.

I thought perhaps I needed to restart my docker images and did try that.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
f14c004ae0d2        prismagraphql/prisma:1.34   "/bin/sh -c /app/sta…"   30 minutes ago      Up 30 minutes       0.0.0.0:4466->4466/tcp   backend_prisma_1
0c5f3517e990        mysql                       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 months ago        Up 21 minutes       3306/tcp, 33060/tcp      latinconexiones_mysql-db_1
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret
        databases:
          default:
            connector: mysql
            host: host.docker.internal
            database: test_db
            user: root
            password: root
            rawAccess: true
            port: '8889'
            migrations: false
```

How can I solve this? It feels like re-initializing Prisma with a different port may work, but that feels like overkill?

Answer (score 0):

check with `docker ps` if any container uses that port, if so stop it if you don't need it, or change the port of your current container.

it may be also that a non-containerized app uses that port: check this with: `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN | grep 4466`

Comment: Thank you Khalil. The problem was that when I switch to Apollo Server it looks for the graphql file at /graphql where as Yoga didn't. Once I updated the .env file to localhost:4444/graphql it worked!